# Add the array to the another array with key as a unique element

Tags: php

I have two arrays the first one like this:

```
Array
(
    [4301] => Array
        (
            [business_unit_id] => 2
            [no_of_invoices] => 1
            [invoice_status_query] => 1
        )

    [4501] => Array
        (
            [business_unit_id] => 1
            [no_of_invoices] => 2
            [invoice_status_query] => 0
        )

)
```

and the other array like this:

```
Array
(
    [4301] => Array
        (
            [business_unit_id] => 2
            [PO_to_be_Approved] => 0
        )

    [4501] => Array
        (
            [business_unit_id] => 1
            [PO_to_be_Approved] => 0
        )

)
```

So how do i get something like this `array` below out of the first and second array?:

```
Array
(
    [4301] => Array
        (   
            [business_unit_id] => 2
            [no_of_invoices] => 1
            [invoice_status_query] => 1
            [business_unit_id] => 2
            [PO_to_be_Approved] => 0
        )

    [4501] => Array
        (
            [business_unit_id] => 1
            [no_of_invoices] => 2
            [invoice_status_query] => 0
            [business_unit_id] => 1
            [PO_to_be_Approved] => 0
        )

)
```

I know array_merge function will create 4 array elements. But i needed to create a new array with keeping Key as a unique element.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php ?

Comment: You should first define what you want. Giving examples isn't a precise definition of how the arrays should be treated. Also, consider combining the two arrays into a third, i.e. treating the inputs as read-only. This often makes it easier to program, because you don't have to mess with changing state. Of course, you can discard one of the inputs and replace it with the output after that, but in order to write the code, leave things unchanged.

Comment: i need to store a array elements of arrray1 and array2, thats what i mention the expected result about. if you see my expected result i have combine all the values of array and array2.

Comment: Is `[business_unit_id] => 1` always the same for both keys like 4501 and 4301?

Comment: yes, its always the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the keys for `[business_unit_id] => 1` are always the same for both keys like 4501 and 4301 you might use [`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php):

```
$array1 = [
    "4301" => [
        "business_unit_id" => 2,
        "no_of_invoices" => 1,
        "invoice_status_query" => 1
    ],
    "4501" => [
        "business_unit_id" => 1,
        "no_of_invoices" => 2,
        "invoice_status_query" => 0
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    "4301" => [
        "business_unit_id" => 2,
        "PO_to_be_Approved" => 0
    ],
    "4501" => [
        "business_unit_id" => 1,
        "PO_to_be_Approved" => 0
    ]
];

$result = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

If you want both keys for `[business_unit_id] => 1` merged in an array you could for example use 2 `foreach` loops with [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => &$value1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($key1 === $key2) {
            $value1 = array_merge_recursive($value1, $value2);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/uia77)

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the second array and add the elements to the first array

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
    $array1[$key] = $value;
}
```

You can't have duplicate keys so the `business_unit_id` from array2 will overwrite any value from array1

Comment: but i have "no_of_invoices" is missing in the array result, missing duplicates is no problem but need to get the result of array1 "key 4301" and "key 4501" array values.